# Add space when a word is too long

Tags: php, string

My problem is the following. I have a string like this:

```
$string = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
```

and I output this string in a container that's 100px wide. Is there any way I can automatically insert a space after 10 characters if any word is longer than 10 characters?

```
$string = chunk_split($string, 10);
```

is not a good solution because it inserts a space in the middle of a word. For example:

```
$string = "This is why chunk_split doesn't work";
$string = chunk_split($string, 10);
echo $string;
// OUTPUT: This is wh y chunk_sp lit doesn' t work
```

The point is that a space character allows the string to create a new line.

---

**Desired Output:**

```
$string = "This is how it should work.";
$string = function_i_am_looking_for($string);
echo $string;
// OUTPUT: This is how it should work.


$string = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
$string = function_i_am_looking_for($string);
echo $string;
// OUTPUT: AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: Insert zero-width joiners.

Comment: If you plan on using this in HTML, look at [CSS word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap)

Comment: or maybe a more intricated way would be making an array and if an item is over 10 characters long, chunk_split it

Comment: Are you just trying to make the long words wrap rather than extending outside their parent element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just looking to force your string to wrap rather than extending outside of its parent element, you can do that directly in css and not have to mess with your string at all:

```
p { 
  width: 100px; 
  word-wrap: break-word; 
}

<p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
```

That'll let the browser figure out where it needs to break rather than you trying to figure it out on the server.

Comment: problem with this solution is that you cannot control where possible break happens. Using `<wbr>` or invisible unicode space is better in that regard - you only insert where split is permissible

Comment: Yeah, it all depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

Use [wordwrap()](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) Wordwrap cuts the sentence by full words before to reach the max width. In the next example I turned `true` the last parameter to force the cut always with 10 characters.

```
$short = wordwrap($string, 10, PHP_EOL, true);
```

another option is

```
$short = wordwrap($string, 10, '<br>', true);
```

However cut by number of characters is not safe since not always the width of the chars is the same (different font types)

The best option is place a `<div>` over the last part of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding [`<wbr/>`](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) instead of a space if you're planing on viewing this in HTML

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\S{10})(?=\S)/', '$1 ', $string);
```

This will insert a space after each consecutive block of 10 non-space characters (`\S`) which are followed by at least one more non-space.

Also, instead of a regular space, you may prefer to instead insert a [soft hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen), U+00AD, or a Unicode [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), U+200B.

---

**Edit:** As sachleen and others have noted, the best solution to the *actual* problem is probably the [CSS word-wrap property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap), specifically `word-wrap: break-word`.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using this in HTML, look at [CSS word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap)

```
#foo { 
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/iqopiy/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the point is to make these "words" not break your layout. Seeing as how long "words" like that are likely not even words, and splitting them up is not likely to make them any more readable...why not just remove them?

`$content = preg_replace("~\w{11,}~","",$content);`

Answer (score 0):

another alternative..

```
$string = preg_replace_callback(
  "~\w{11,}~",
  create_function(
    '$m',
    'return chunk_split($m[0],10," ");'
  ),
  $string);
```